# bind action to <select>

Tags: javascript, html, select

Good evening , i'm trying to create a "Menu" and would like to bind actions for each element of the Menu .

I just started html (10mn ago)...

So i read that i ve to use onchange="myfunction()"
So i tried :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function Load(obj) {
     if(obj.value == "X1"){
        alert('X1');
     }
     if(obj.value == "X2"){
        alert('X2');
     }
  }
 </script>
 <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>Developper Informations</title>
 </head>
 <body>
      <form method="post" action="traitement.php">
        <label>Langages de programmation  : </label>
        <select onchange="Load()" name="Languages" id="Languages">
         <optgroup label="XX1">
             <option value="X1">X1</option>
             <option value="X2">X2</option>
         </optgroup>
        </select>
      </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

But won't work ... i tried several options ...

Comment: What about it didn't work? Do you see any errors in your console? You aren't passing anything to the `Load` function. Are you expected `obj` to have some value?

Comment: `onchange=Load()` isn't passing anything to your function

Comment: well i tried Load(element) won't work idrk what to do ...

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you need to pass the `select` as a parameter to `Load()`

Try: `onchange="Load(this)"`

If you don't pass a parameter to `Load()`, `obj` will be undefined. There are probably errors in your developer console (press F12 to view) saying `value` does not exist.

Comment: @rsn Yes it will. `this` in that context refers to the element which you add the binding to. In this case, that's the `<select>` element.

Comment: ReferenceError: Load is not defined; Then again, this might just be JSFiddle's problem. Lastly, just to be THAT guy, it's a little more elegant to avoid inline styling or JS in your HTML, but that might not be here nor there.

Comment: @rsn On JSFiddle, inline events for some reason can't communicate with the JavaScript block. Try putting the script in the HTML section like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/km79sfg5/).

Comment: @4castle So I've noticed :).

Comment: @4castle You can also click the settings gear in the JavaScript panel and change the Load Type to "No wrap - in <head>". It's the same thing as if you had put the script section in a script tag in the head.

Comment: @MikeC Thanks! That's actually super helpful. I've been wondering how to fix that for ages

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/k4dj0n0x/1/

```
function Load(obj) {
    if(obj.value == "X1"){
        alert('X1');
     }
     else if (obj.value == "X2"){
        alert('X2');
     }
  }

  var languages = document.getElementById("Languages");
  languages.addEventListener("change", Load(languages));
```